# How to access User model through django.contrib

Tags: python, django

I have implemented a custom User manager. However, for some django features, such as auth_user forgot password, I would like to be able to use the standard django way to reference a user: `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. But this is the error I get when I try:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.all()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Desktop/CueCloud/Django/Cuecloud/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 273, in __get__
self.model._meta.object_name, self.model._meta.swapped
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'main.User'
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: This makes no sense. That is *not* the standard Django way if you've swapped your user model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong about "standard way to reference a user". You have a [referencing-the-user-model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) section in the Django docs which tells you how to do that.

Basically, use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`.